# tikz: specifying coordiantes system in 3d

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3d

currently I am working with TikZ program in latex to draw a 3d figure. I need to redefine a coordinates system in 3d. The following is a MWE I tried:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x={(0:1)},y={(60:1)},z={(30:1cm)}]
        \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0);
        \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0);
        \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And it gives the followings figure:
[image]

But when I tried to change the z coordinate as z={(30:1)} (without dimension), it gives another picture as follows:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x={(0:1)},y={(60:1)},z={(30:1)}]
        \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0);
        \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0);
        \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

So I wonder how the XYZ vectors are rotated? Are they all rotated based on the vector (1cm,0)? I didn't find the answer in the pgf manual and search for help here.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: (30:1) is a coordinate in the recently defined coordinate system x = (0:1), y = (60:1) while (30:1cm) is a coordinate in the canvas coordinate system. You shouldn't define the xyz coordinate system with coordinates in itself. (There are ways around this by evaluating the three coordinates first and only then setting the vectors accordingly.)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks for your reply. So the latter case (z=(30:1cm)) is not correct? In the former case (x=(0:1), y=(60:1), z=(30:1)) how are y and z vectors rotated? I mean for example, is y vector  rotated by 60° based on vector (1,0)? And how about z, also based on (1,0)?

Comment: @RonghuaXu: Nothing is rotated, so your question does not make sense. TikZ only works in 2D. The third Z coordinate is just a convenient way to add extra X and Y. -a fake projected Z. -see the comment